# Null collection with mongodb driver for nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have shifted from mongoose to mongodb driver 3.1.13 for nodejs. My db resides on mlab. My problem is I am not even able to create a collection. Collection returned is null. Am I doing it the wrong way? Is there anything like save() function as we do have in mongoose.

[image for the code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO7Qb.png)

Comment: Did you checked the `err`? Is it `Null`?

Comment: @Tolsee... It is giving - "MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed at basicWriteValidations at .....".... why is this so ?

Comment: There is a problem while connecting with the server. Please see the error code and try to see documentation about the error. Also, update the question with a full error message(Mainly the error code.)